# Can I use typings from a library dependency in my main application?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, angular-library, npm-package

I am developing an Angular library (let's name it libA), and this library has a depencency (libB).

Then I upgrade libA version and libB dependency version in the new libA version. When I update libA version in my application it can't access libB new version types from the application. It seems it only updates libA version in the node_modules of the application, and not libB.

What is the recommended approach? Should I explicity export libB types in libA or should I explicity update also libB in my application? Or add libB as a peerDependency in libA?

Thanks in advance.